# Issue querying parse data

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have saved data in a class that stores group names in Parse. Each group name also has a relation that contains all the group info. I have tried to query the data in the relation but the output has resulted in nothing.

The first image is the class ("Groups") that contains the group name along with the group info relation column, the second image is the "GroupInfo" relation containing all the group data.

[image]

[image]

The objects have been saved like so:

```
let groups = PFObject(className: "Groups")
let groupinfo = PFObject(className: "Groupinfo")
@IBAction func CreateNewGroupAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    groupinfo["Score"] = 1
    groupinfo["Project"] = "Test"
    beaterinfo.save()


    groups["GroupName"] = "DFG"
 let relation = groups.relationForKey("Groupinfo")
    relation.addObject(groupinfo)

    beatergroups.save()

}
```

This was my attempt at querying the relational data:

```
@IBAction func QueryDataAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    var groupnamesquery = PFQuery(className: "Groups")
  groupnamesquery.whereKey("GroupInfo", equalTo: "DFG")
    beatergroupnamesquery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil && object != nil  {

            if let object = object as? [PFObject] {
                for objects in object {
                let relation = objects.relationForKey("GroupInfo")
               println(relation.valueForKey("Project")!)


                }

            }

        } else {

            println("Error: \(error)")
        }


    }



}
```

Any help on querying the relational data would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Error in second line of "QueryDataAction":

`groupnamesquery.whereKey("GroupInfo", equalTo: "DFG")`

should be

`groupnamesquery.whereKey("**GroupName**", equalTo: "DFG")`.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. Unfortunately that made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The first query only returns the "Groups" objects which do not contain any "GroupInfo" information. So if you do a nested query, you should be able to retrieve the GroupInfo object.

```
@IBAction func QueryDataAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    var groupnamesquery = PFQuery(className: "Groups")
    groupnamesquery.whereKey("GroupName", equalTo: "DFG")
    beatergroupnamesquery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ 
        (object: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && object != nil  {
            if let object = object as? [PFObject] {
                for objects in object {

                    // create a relation based on the groupsinfo key
                    let relation = objects.relationForKey("GroupInfo")

                    // generate a query based on that relation
                    let query = relation.query()

                    // execute the query
                    let groupInfo = query.findObjects()

                    println(groupInfo["Project"])
                }
            }
        } else {
            println("Error: \(error)")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I get an error at the "println(groupInfo["Project"])" line saying that: Cannot add subscript of value [AnyObject]? with an index of type string.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
@IBAction func QueryDataAction(sender: AnyObject) {

var groupnamesquery = PFQuery(className: "Groups")
groupnamesquery.whereKey("GroupName", equalTo: "DFG")
beatergroupnamesquery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ 
    (object: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil && object != nil  {
        if let object = object as? [PFObject] {
            for objects in object {


                let relation = objects.relationForKey("GroupInfo")


                let query = relation.query()
  query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objecx: [AnyObject]?, erro: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil && objecx != nil {

                            if let objecx = objecx as? [PFObject] {
                                for obecxs in objecx {

                                let infos: AnyObject? = obecxs.valueForKey("Project")!

                                    println(infos!)
                                }


                            }
```